# I am getting "firebase storage is not defined" error while trying to implement firebase for my react app

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

I am creating a signup page that requires thumbnail. firebase authentication is working fine but the i am getting this error for the storage

[image: signup error]

```js
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/firestore'
import 'firebase/auth'
import 'firebase/storage'

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyDjltfm2KlCLu1wYpbKl5A9pnxGv_7dxMc",
  authDomain: "sunodojo.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "sunodojo",
  storageBucket: "sunodojo.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "482721025907",
  appId: "1:482721025907:web:96cd2758994da9be01bf06"
};

// initializing firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)

// initializing services
const projectFirestore = firebase.firestore()
const projectAuth = firebase.auth()
const projectStorage = firebase.storage()

// timestamp
const timestamp = firebase.firestore.Timestamp


export { projectFirestore, projectAuth, projectStorage, timestamp }
```

Comment: Can you share your `package.json`? Also the error doesn't seem to be from this file. Can you share the file where you are trying to use `projectStorage`?

Comment: I tired to paste the code but it says too long. Help please! how can i share

Comment: Can you try creating a [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com) and sharing a link?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/ZcRiUg4L

Comment: Hi, I fixed the error. Thank you. you made me review the file where i'm trying to use the ProjectStorage